# scrapy pipeline error using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am completely lost.  here's my pipeline.  When I run it, im getting an error that says

```
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\bff\bff\pipelines.py", line 42, in process_item
    cursor.execute(add_Product)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 492, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

As you can see by the commented code, I have tried a few different ways.  At first, I was doing it just as I saw in the examples but was getting an error that sadi item was not defined when I put (item['StoreName']) in the VALUES line instead of defining it up above as Name = item['StoreName'] 
I;m using the mySQL.connector that I installed from the mqsql.org website.  Thanks in advance

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Define your item pipelines here
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector  
#from scrapy.extensions import DropItem
#from bff.items import ItemInfo

class mySQLPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    Path = item['ProdPath']
    UPC = item['ProdUPC']
    Model = item['ProdModel']
    Desc = item['ProdDesc']
    Price = item['ProdPrice']
    Stock = item['InStock']
    #Ships = item['Ships']
    Name = item['StoreName']


    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='*****', password='*****',
                                  host='127.0.0.1',
                                  port='****',
                                  database='scrapyinfo')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    #add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products (ProdName)"
    #               "VALUES (%s), (Name);")

    add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products, (ProdName, ProdPath, ProdUPC, ProdModel, ProdDesc, ProdPrice, InStock, Ships, StoreName)"
                   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (Name, Path, UPC, Model, Desc, Price, Stock, Name))
                    #item['Ships'],



    #Add new product
    cursor.execute(add_Product)

    # Make sure data is committed to the database
    cnx.commit()

    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
    return item
```

**EDIT.  Here is my new code**

```
`

from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector  
#from scrapy.extensions import DropItem
#from bff.items import ItemInfo

class mySQLPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        Product = item['ProdName']      
        Path = item['ProdPath']
        UPC = item['ProdUPC']
        Model = item['ProdModel']
        Desc = item['ProdDesc']
        Price = item['ProdPrice']
        Stock = item['InStock']
        #Ships = item['Ships']
        Name = item['StoreName']


        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='****', password='****',
                                      host='127.0.0.1',
                                      port='****',
                                      database='****')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
 #       add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products (ProdName, StoreName) VALUES (%s, %s,)", Product, Name,)
 #       add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products, (ProdName)"
 #                      "VALUES (%s)", (Name))
 #                      "VALUES (%(Name)s)")
        add_Product = ("INSERT INTO walmart_products "
                        "(ProdName, ProdPath, ProdUPC, ProdModel, ProdDesc, ProdPrice, InStock, StoreName) "
                        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
                        #item['Ships'],

        data_Product = (Product, Path, UPC, Model, Desc, Price, Stock, Name)                                        

        #Add new product
        cursor.execute(add_Product, data_Product)

        # Make sure data is committed to the database
        cnx.commit()

        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
        return item
```

`

Comment: are the fields populated with a list or string?

Comment: no lists.  Here is the code for my items.py `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class ItemInfo(scrapy.Item):
    ProdPath = scrapy.Field()
    ProdUPC = scrapy.Field()
    ProdName = scrapy.Field()
    ProdModel = scrapy.Field()
    ProdDesc = scrapy.Field()
    InStock = scrapy.Field()
    ProdPrice = scrapy.Field()
    StoreName = scrapy.Field()
    Ships = scrapy.Field()
    pass`

Comment: share how you populate the item, not the items declaration.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to figure out how to get the code to show correctly in the reply.  Here's an example of how I am populating the items.                                    ` def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector (response)
        item = ItemInfo()

        item['ProdPath'] = sel.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()
        item['ProdUPC'] = sel.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:upc"]/@content').extract()`

Comment: `.extract()` gives a list.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was default.  If its just a string do I leave off the .extract () and will that fix my issue you think?

Comment: I tried modify the code as you suggested and am still getting the same error along with this new error too. "IndexError: list index out of range"      Here is an example of what I changed the code to `item['ProdPath'] = sel.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').extract()[0]`   Any other thought?

Comment: Any other thoughts on this?  I have been scouring through here and google for days and can't seem to get anywhere.  I just tried replacing this line `"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (Name, Path, UPC, Model, Desc, Price, Stock, Name))` with just some basic info like this. `"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ("VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ('Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', 'Test2', ))`  I got the same error.    My mind is fried.

Comment: first check if the number of `%s` is equal to the ones formatting, and second, to format on python, you need to use something like `"my string %s, %s" % ('foo', 'bar')`, and you are not passing `%` but a `,`

Comment: I checked the first part and made sure there were the same number of %s.  They were different so I corrected but same error.  I don't quite understand what your are saying in the second part.  Also, here is the sample code from the MySQL website that I referenced to programming this.  I tried every variation I could find in there. Thanks (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

Comment: don't use comma (`,`) between the string and the tuple, use `%`

Comment: I've not stopped googling on this and I have changed the code.  See the original post edit for a look at the new code.   I feel a lot better about it but am now getting an error that says **Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type**  I'm not sure if what you said would still apply but I'll try it anyway.  Would I make it like so? `data_Product = (Product% Path% UPC% Model% Desc% Price% Stock% Name)`

Comment: I can't help you beyond of my previous comments, I recommend you learn some python first.

Comment: I thought that's exactly what I was trying to do. Hence the questions.  Thank you very much attempting to help.  Anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is stuck where I was, I coudn't figure it out.  I got frustrated and stopped using the mysql.connector and instead used the MySQLdb.  Once I switched to that then everything went through just fine.